# Error on joy_node (Couldn't open joystick)

Tags: ros, joy-node, joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have an error on joy_node.
I wanted to use joystick to control Ar.Drone. So I used joy package. At the first time, I successfully used joystick("rosrun joy joy_node".)
But next time I executed joy_node, an error occurred.

```
[ERROR] [1473937621.294455702]: Couldn't open joystick dev/input/js1. Will retry every second.
```

Then, I tried some solutions.
First, I checked what is the joystick's name.

```
ls -l /dev/input/js*
crw-rw-rw-  1 root root 13, 0  9月 15 19:06 /dev/input/js0
crw-rw-rw-+ 1 root root 13, 1  9月 15 19:24 /dev/input/js1
```

Plugging and unplugging, I could see my joystick was js1.

Second, I changed permissions of /dev/input/js1 to 777 and set the parameter.

```
sudo chmod a+rw /dev/input/js1
rosparam set joy_node/dev "dev/input/js1"
```

After all I couldn't solve this problem...

Thank you for any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243824/error-on-joy_node-(couldn%27t-open-joystick)/) by [Pato](https://answers.ros.org/users/24802/pato/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-09-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> rosparam set joy_node/dev "dev/input/js1"
> ```

The path to the joystick device is `/dev/input/js1`, not `dev/input/js1` (note the starting `/`).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-09-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pato](https://answers.ros.org/users/24802/pato/) on 2016-09-15**:
Thank you for the quick answer. I didn't notice the simple mistake.Thanks to you, I was able to use the joystick!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-09-16**:
No problem, good you got it to work.